# Sistema de repetição como armazenar um valor

Tags: c, matemática

> Faça um programa que receba a idade, a altura e o peso de 25 pessoas. Calcule e mostre:
>
> A quantidade de pessoas com idade superior a 50;
>
> A média das alturas das pessoas entre 10 a 20 anos;
>
> A percentagem de pessoas com peso inferior a 40 KG entre todas as pessoas analisadas.

Como que eu faço para armazenar todas as alturas que o usuário digitar para depois calcular a média de todos os valores sem precisar colocar um monte de `printf()` e `scanf()`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int idade[25], i, sup50=0, peso40=0;
    float altura[25], media_altura, peso[25], porcentagem, idade10_20=0;

    for(i=0; i<25; i++)

    {

        printf("DIGITE A IDADE DA %d PESSOA: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &idade[i]);

        printf("DIGITE A ALTURA DA %d PESSOA: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &altura[i]);

        printf("DIGITE O PESO DA %d PESSOA: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &peso[i]);

        printf("\n");


            if(idade[i]>50)
            {
                sup50++;
            }

            if(idade[i]>=10 && idade[i]<=20)
            {
              // MINHA DÚVIDA É AQUI
            }
            if(peso[i]>40)
            {
                peso40++;
                porcentagem = 100*peso40/25;
            }

    }

    printf("\n\nA QUANTIDADE DE PESSOAS COM IDADE SUPERIOR Á 50 É %d\n\n", sup50);
    printf("A MÉDIA DAS ALTURAS DE PESSOAS ENTRE 10 E 20 ANO É %.2f\n\n",  ? );
    printf("A PORCENTAGEM DE PESSOAS COM PESO INFERIOR Á 40 KG É %.2f%%\n\n", porcentagem);

system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código faz coisas demais seja no mecanismo, seja no requisito. Tem muita variável, e outras coisas sem necessidade, mas principal está armazenando coisas que o exercício não pede. Só precisa saber quantos tem mais de 50 anos e isso foi feito, precisa saber quantas pessoas são jovens e a soma se suas alturas, com essas duas informações é só fazer uma divisão simples para a média de altura entre essas pessoas e finalmente a porcentagem de pessoas com mais de 40Kg só deve ser calculada no final do laço, nele só deve fazer contar quantas pessoas são.

Não é questão de programação é de interpretação de texto e propor uma solução matemática.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int idade, sup50 = 0, peso40 = 0, jovens = 0;
    float altura, peso, alturas;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        printf("DIGITE A IDADE DA %d PESSOA: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &idade);
        printf("DIGITE A ALTURA DA %d PESSOA: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &altura);
        printf("DIGITE O PESO DA %d PESSOA: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &peso);
        printf("\n");
        if (idade > 50) sup50++;
        if (idade >= 10 && idade <= 20) {
            jovens++;
            alturas += altura;
        }
        if (peso > 40) peso40++;
    }
    printf("\n\nA QUANTIDADE DE PESSOAS COM IDADE SUPERIOR Á 50 É %d\n\n", sup50);
    printf("A MÉDIA DAS ALTURAS DE PESSOAS ENTRE 10 E 20 ANO É %.2f\n\n", alturas / jovens);
    printf("A PORCENTAGEM DE PESSOAS COM PESO INFERIOR Á 40 KG É %.2f%%\n\n", peso40 * 0.25);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rZdDgj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qeqobevk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CalcAverage.c).

Comment: Como sempre você me ajudando, muito obrigado amigo !!!!

Comment: O que eu tava quebrando a cabeça era nesse operador += era isso que eu tava precisando aprender, eu tô quebrando a cabeça em muitas questões por causa desse operador que eu não conhecia.